# provide Custom Entities to Google NLP engine

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I want the Google NLP engine to be able to recognize custom entities.
I have a company called Hint and I want it to tag it as an organization.
'I like hint'
or
'I like Hint' 
does not tag Hint as a organization. It tags Hint as "Other" entity type.

Is there some key word to provide to Google NLP so I can talk to it. For example can I pre process my text such as

I like %CUSTOM_ENTITY%

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently have a mechanism for adding custom entities.

I'd be interested to learn more about what you'd like to do. How many entities would you like to put in? What kinds of information would you like to include? Are you thinking of a list of entity names and types?

Comment: I want to be able specify to Google NLP that I am trying to track a certain entity across comments. Often when companies are named after regular words, comments about the company can get misinterpreted and influence the sentiment ( or perhaps not influence the sentiment enough). I would like to specify the entity I am trying to track (even provide the entity type to Google) eg. CUSTOM_ENTITY='Hint' ENTITY_TYPE='Organization' .